# Does analyzer "pattern" support other languages?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

when i use analyzer: "pattern" on "text" field it returns results only in English:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "pattern",
  "text": "The 2 QUICK Brown-Foxes."
}
```

the response :

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "the",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "2",
            "start_offset": 4,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "quick",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "brown",
            "start_offset": 12,
            "end_offset": 17,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "foxes",
            "start_offset": 18,
            "end_offset": 23,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

but when the text is in other languages it doesn't return results:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "pattern",
  "text": "БЫСТРЫХ бурых лисицы."
}
```

the response :

```
{
    "tokens": []
}
```

analyzer pattern should support all languages

Comment: You should try the russian language analyzer instead of the pattern one.

Comment: i should use pattern analyzer for all languages

Comment: May I ask why the pattern analyzer is of interest to you? If you don't supply any pattern, the default one is `\W`, i.e. split on non words. The `standard analyzer` does the same and works for any language, also for russian, try it out

Comment: standard analyzer doesn't' split by all the special characters  for example: 
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text" : "fgjdv.cfdffds "
}
is different than:
{
  "analyzer": "pattern",
  "text" : "fgjdv.cfdffds "
}

Comment: `fgjdv.cfdffds` is no language... Maybe you should modify your question to explain the use case you're after, i.e. explain what you're trying to accomplish, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

> analyzer pattern should support all languages

That was never an intention for the pattern analyzer. The pattern analyzer was designed to match regex patterns in the input string and split the sting into tokens on every match while ignoring the part that it matched. It wasn't intended to be used in its default configurations neither. You are expected to specify your own pattern you it to match on. The only reason you can do what you did is that elasticsearch requires all analyzers to work without being configured, so developers needed to pick some default values for all parameters, and they happen to pick `\W+`.

If you take a look at [regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\W+` simply means 1 or more characters other then lowercase latin alphabet characters `a`-`z`, upper case characters `A`-`Z` or numbers `0`-`9`. All other characters including Cyrillic alphabet characters are treated as word dividers.

> Does analyzer "pattern" support other languages?

That's a good question. The pattern analyzer doesn't care about languages, it cares about patterns. So, I can specify a pattern to match all non-Cyrillic characters:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_cyrillic_analyzer": {
          "type":      "pattern",
          "pattern":   "[^\u0400-\u04ff]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_pattern_analyzer",
  "text": "The 2 бурые лисы jumped over the lazy dog's bone."
}
```

In this case it will produce:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "бурые",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "лисы",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Or you can do something like

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_alphabetic_analyzer": {
          "type":      "pattern",
          "pattern":   "[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_alphabetic_analyzer",
  "text": "The 2 бурые лисы jumped over the lazy dog's bone."
}
```

In which case it will omit all non unicode alphabetic characters. It is a powerful tool in good hands but you need to learn how to use it. If you are only starting with elasticsearch I would suggest going with `standard` analyzer unless you have some specific issues that you want to address, in which case, please state the issues and we will try to suggest you a proper solution to address them.